# Store new value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to change the value of an object of an array but seems like values are not saving.I read about immutable objects but there must be somehow a way to do that.I would be glad for any help, thank you.

```
app.get('/api/reservations',function(req,res) {
Rezervari.getReservations(function(err,reserv){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    let datas = reserv
    for( var i=0;i < reserv.length ;i++){
      let changetime = dateformat(datas[i].data).format("MM-DD-YYYY")
       datas[i].data = changetime;
       datas[i].data = dateformat(datas[i].data).format("MM-DD-YYYY")
        console.log(datas[i].data) // 2018-09-17T21:00:00.000Z
        console.log(changetime) // 09-18-2018
    }
    res.json(datas);
});
});
```

Edit:  The object is `reserv` or `datas`(same array).I want to change field `data`of `reserv` from ISO  format to `MM-DD-YYYY` format.Value is changed in var `changeTime` but in the array value of `data` is not changed.

Comment: The problem is not clear. Which object do you want to change? Please explain a little bit better what you are trying to do.

Comment: @HugoTeixeira So I am trying to change date format and send the new array with new values for data object.Reserv is an array of objects  and datas is just a variable I tried to make it  works(it is not working).So I am changing the date format and want to edit only the date field using variable changetime.The new value is not saving into datas or reserv var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if the objects in the array were [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Here's an example of how you could implement something similar:

```js
const handler = {
    get: function(obj, prop) {
        if (prop === 'data') {
            return this._data.toISOString();
        }
    },
    set: function(obj, prop, value) {
        if (prop === 'data') {
            this._data = new Date(value);
        }
    }
};

let obj = new Proxy({}, handler);
obj.data = '2018-09-17';
console.log(obj.data); // returns '2018-09-17T00:00:00.000Z'
```

If this is your case, and you want to avoid the proxy behavior, you could map the original array to a new one:

```
res.json(datas.map(item => {
    return {
        data: dateformat(item.data).format("MM-DD-YYYY")
        /* extract any other properties you're interested in from the original objects */
    };
}));
```

Comment: I assigned data to  new Proxy(reserv,{})    - reserv is the arrray of objects I want to edit.It is not working , same output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try cloning the Javascript objects, populating a new array and returning it. Here is an example:

```
let datas = [];
for (let i = 0; i < reserv.length ; i++){
  const clone = Object.assign({}, reserv[i]);
  clone.data = dateformat(reserv[i].data).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
  datas.push(clone);
}
res.json(datas);
```